# linq - multiple where statements if variables are not null

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement, where-clause

I would like the query to return from 
`WANOM_DETAILS & STRDT tables where  PIPELINE = 'F' AND HISTORICAL_FLAG <> 'T' AND INSTALLATION = 'EA' AND ANOMALY_CLASS = 'Critical'`.

The if statements work correctly, but at the moment the query is only returning from 
`WANOM_DETAILS & STRDT tables where ANOMALY_CLASS = 'Critical'` as this is the final line before the `model.ToList();`

Any help would be much appreciated. Here is the code;

```
        strdt = "EA";
        anom_class = "Critical";

        var models = db.WANOM_DETAILS;

        var model = models.Where(wanom_details => wanom_details.STRDT.PIPELINE == "F");
        model = models.Where(wanom_details => wanom_details.STRDT.HISTORICAL_FLAG != "T");
        if (strdt != "")
        {
            model = models.Where(wanom_details => wanom_details.INSTALLATION == strdt);
        }
        if (anom_class != "")
        {
            model = models.Where(wanom_details => wanom_details.ANOMALY_CLASS == anom_class);
        }
        if (subdt != "")
        {
            model = models.Where(wanom_details => wanom_details.WANOM.SUBSTRUCTURE == subdt);
        }
        if (comp != "")
        {
            model = models.Where(wanom_details => wanom_details.WANOM.TYPE + "-" + wanom_details.WANOM.IDENT == comp);
        }

        return PartialView("_SiteAnomalyGridViewPartial", model.ToList());
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but will using model.Where without the s on all places except the first solve your problem?

Comment: You need to keep piping on models.  Should be `models = models.Where` everywhere

Comment: Yes removing the s on all places except the first has solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Each `if` can override the `model` instance, sure you want that?

Answer (score 0):

you can chain the results of Where, so:

```
X.Where(x => x.Prop > 1 && x.Prop2 == "1")
```

You can achieve the same result concatenation of two Where:

```
X.Where(x => x.Prop > 1).Where(x.Prop2 == "1").
```

So in your case you can do this:

```
strdt = "EA";
anom_class = "Critical";

var models = db.WANOM_DETAILS;

models = models.Where(wanom_details => wanom_details.STRDT.PIPELINE == "F");
models = models.Where(wanom_details => wanom_details.STRDT.HISTORICAL_FLAG != "T");
if (strdt != "")
{
    models = models.Where(wanom_details => wanom_details.INSTALLATION == strdt);
}
if (anom_class != "")
{
    models = models.Where(wanom_details => wanom_details.ANOMALY_CLASS == anom_class);
}
if (subdt != "")
{
    models = models.Where(wanom_details => wanom_details.WANOM.SUBSTRUCTURE == subdt);
}
if (comp != "")
{
    models = models.Where(wanom_details => wanom_details.WANOM.TYPE + "-" + wanom_details.WANOM.IDENT == comp);
}

return PartialView("_SiteAnomalyGridViewPartial", models.ToList());
```

#### EDIT:

when you use a long `Where` expression which chain conditions with `&&` operator, the sql generetd made in accordance conditions with `And`.
However, when you chain `IQueryable` with some `Where` expression, the `linq-to-sql` genereate seperate select-where for each, and wrap all in Union query.
The db-server may optimize, but to me it feels awkward.
to get the first result, you can use the greate [predicatebuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) extension method:

```
strdt = "EA";
anom_class = "Critical";

var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<ClassOfWANOM_DETAILS>();

predicate.And(wanom_details => wanom_details.STRDT.PIPELINE == "F");
predicate.And(wanom_details => wanom_details.STRDT.HISTORICAL_FLAG != "T");
if (strdt != "")
    predicate.And(wanom_details => wanom_details.INSTALLATION == strdt);
if (anom_class != "")
    predicate.And(wanom_details => wanom_details.ANOMALY_CLASS == anom_class);
if (subdt != "")
    predicate.And(wanom_details => wanom_details.WANOM.SUBSTRUCTURE == subdt);
if (comp != "")
    predicate.And(wanom_details => wanom_details.WANOM.TYPE + "-" + wanom_details.WANOM.IDENT == comp);

return PartialView("_SiteAnomalyGridViewPartial", db.WANOM_DETAILS.Where(predicate).ToList());
```